# CANbus adapter stuff in 11-bit mode

Tags: canbus

I have a PEAK canbus adapter (USB) connected to my Linux box, access from Qt C++ program.  While all works well, when I receive frames they are all SFF (11-bit) ID's.  candumps are all 11-bit ID's.  Even if I send EFF (29-bit) frames, it only shows incoming frames in SFF.

The same happens if I use candump, all frames show SFF ID's.

However, after I switched my laptop to Windows and ran PEAK viewer, and then back to Linux, suddenly my frames were all showing in EFF in candump.

Is there something I need to set (in Linux/ip command/qt c++) to force the adapter to use EFF mode?

Comment: This is still speculative, but it would sound like the program under windows either works differently, or loaded a different firmware into the canbus adapter.

Comment: But what you wrote is a useful bug report. Just contact PEAK support, I guess?